# Flask with redis - disable cache during pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, caching, flask

I implemented a Redis cache in my Flask app using `Flask-Caching==1.3.3`, but obviously some of my endpoint unit tests are now failing because the responses are cached, making some POST/PUT tests fail.

Is there some good way to disable the cache during unit tests? I'm using `pytest==3.5.0`

Eg. this fails because the old entry is returned from cache:

```
   def test_updating_biography(self):
        """Should update the current newest entry with the data in the JSON."""
        response = self.app.put(
            "/api/1.0/biography/",
            data=json.dumps(
                dict(
                    short="UnitTest Updated newest short",
                    full="UnitTest Updated newest full",
                )
            ),
            content_type="application/json"
        )

        get_bio = self.app.get("/api/1.0/biography/")
        biodata = json.loads(get_bio.get_data().decode())

        self.assertEquals(200, response.status_code)
        self.assertEquals(200, get_bio.status_code)
>       self.assertEquals("UnitTest Updated newest short", biodata["biography"][0]["short"])
E       AssertionError: 'UnitTest Updated newest short' != 'UnitTest fourth short'
E       - UnitTest Updated newest short
E       + UnitTest fourth short

tests/biography/test_biography_views.py:100: AssertionError
```

I tried for example:

```
def setUp(self):
    app.config["CACHE_TYPE"] = None
    app.config["CACHE_REDIS_URL"] = ""
    self.app = app.test_client()
```

And also `app.config["CACHE_TYPE"] = "null"` and `app.config["CACHE_TYPE"] = ""`, but it is still using the cache in the unit test.

I tried this one, but it's of course outside of app context:

```
@cache.cached(timeout=0)
def test_updating_biography(self):
```

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but when testing apps that use celery/redis, we configure celery to use an in-memory broker. In absence of a solution for disabling caching, perhaps you could consider using a setup or teardown method to clear the cache.

Comment: @sytech: Ah, that's a great idea since I only test a single app with this redis.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comment, sytech's idea works for me since I only test a single app with this redis. Obviously if you use a shared redis for multiple apps, this might not work for you. But for my case, it worked perfectly and can be repeated without issues:

```
import unittest

from flask_caching import Cache
from app import app, db


class TestBiographyViews(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        """Add some test entries to the database, so we can test getting the latest one."""

        # Clear redis cache completely
        cache = Cache()
        cache.init_app(app, config={"CACHE_TYPE": "redis"})
        with app.app_context():
            cache.clear()

        self.app = app.test_client()
```

The above is all you need. The rest of the test cases can be as normal. Works for me.

Comment: Actually, it's not 100 % perfect yet. When I run the full test suite, this does not clear the cache all the time for some reason. Maybe it does not clear it fast enough until a new test begins?

Comment: Scratch that, one cleanup commit was accidentally deleted in one tearDown of the local branch, which rippled to multiple tests.

Comment: Hi, How can i apply this to the test itself? Like i have this test and i want to clear is cache: ```@patch("dev_maintenance.machines.get_azure_compute_client")  
  def test_get_azure_machine_info (get_azure_compute_client):
       
        with app.app_context():
            ret = get_azure_machine_info("hdfs-test-eu-w","test-eu-w-01")
            assert (ret == get_azure_compute_client.return_value.virtual_machines.get.return_value)
            get_azure_compute_client.return_value.virtual_machines.get.assert_called_once_with(
                "rg1", "m1", expand="instanceView")```

Comment: @PatrickJosé You can also call the above within the test, eg. `act`, `assert`, `clear cache`, `act`, `assert`. If you do it multiple times, I would move it to a helper function.